# how to implement flutter Text to Speech in my flutter project

Tags: android, iphone, flutter, plugins, cloud

I want to implement Cloud Speech-to-Text (Google API) to my Flutter application. Do you know if  it's possible and where I can get some helpful information or instruction of how to do it ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want Speech-to-Text,

Use android native plastform-channels.

Link :

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

Flow :

flutter button click -> android native Speech-to-Text api -> flutter text show